# What exactly is an input/output stream?

Tags: java, stream

I’ve written code to spec that must be capable of taking in text from an input stream and writing it out through an output stream. The code is made to encrypt messages from a file or from the user entering, and either writing it to the command prompt or to a file. How can the general class of input/output stream handle both of these things, and what type of argument do i give to the parameters of the function that fit the spec of input stream and output stream?

Answer (score 0):

your functions *might* be something like:

```
public void encryptFile(String inFile, String outFile) {
   ...
}

public void encryptConsoleToFile(String outFile) {
   ...
}
```

or maybe am I misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 0):

A input/output stream represents any stream of data coming from some source that is either coming into your code or going away from it. Specifically:

An input stream represents data coming from some source that can be read, a producer of data. Whether or not the length of data is known is dependent on the source. Examples of this are input streams to read from files (FileInputStream object in java), read from networks, read from existing byte arrays (ByteArrayInputStream), etc. A file for example will produce data when read via the input stream until the end of file is reached whereas something like an ongoing TCP connection would produce data until the connection is terminated.

An output stream behaves in the exact same way except it is used for writing data from your program to the target destination. Writing to a file (FileOutputStream), writing to a TCP stream, writing to a target byte array are all examples of this.

The so-called specifications of your input/output stream are tied directly to what source/destination you are reading from/writing to. For example, when writing to a console, you may elect to use line-buffering so that the user can see the output near-immediately whereas writing to a file you can use a larger buffer to improve performance.

In java specifically, the [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) and [OutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) class define the basic specifications of all I/O streams in java.

Answer (score 0):

> What exactly is an input/output stream?

[`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) and [`OutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) are two separate abstract classes. I recommend reading through and understanding their documentation.

> How can the general class of input/output stream handle both of these things, and what type of argument do i give to the parameters of the function that fit the spec of input stream and output stream?

They are generally not implemented by the same class (and since they are abstract classes, it's not possible to have a class extend both). There is one class hierarchy for input, another for output.

Comment: Just being pedantic, but they're abstract classes and not interfaces.

Comment: @CPUTerminator - whoops - fixed - I tend to think of them as interfaces in my head and forgot that they aren't actually interfaces.